# Abstract factory pattern with constructor arguments

Tags: scala, inheritance, factory, composition, factory-pattern

I have the following two ways to use the Abstract Factory pattern

**Approach 1**

```
abstract class Dough {
 def getDoughType: String
}

abstract class Sauce {
 def getSauceType: String
}

abstract class AbstractIngredientsFactory {
 def createDough: Dough
 def createSauce: Sauce
}

class ThinDough extends Dough {
  def getDoughType: String = "Thin Dough !!!"
}

class RedSauce extends Sauce {
  def getSauceType: String = "Red Sauce !!!"
}

class ChicagoStoreIngredientsFactory extends AbstractIngredientsFactory {
  def createDough: Dough = new ThinDough
  def createSauce: Sauce = new RedSauce
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
 //no longer seems like a factory
 case class IngredientsFactory(dough: Dough, sauce: Sauce)

 // concrete instance
 val chicagoIngrediendtsFactory = new IngredientsFactory(new ThinDough, new RedSauce)
```

Approach 2 though no longer resembles a standard factory, it seems to serve the same purpose of encapsulating specific ingredients to be used by a specific  store. 
But approach 2 depends on composition and I don't need to create implementations for each region.

Is approach 2 an anti-pattern ?

Comment: I suggest you to look at "Scala & Design Patterns" by Fredric LØkke. I found it originaly on old Scala site, but now it's available [here](https://fdocuments.net/document/frederik-thesis.html). It's master degree thesis, but it's good quality and you can find some really good ideas here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 2 is not the factory pattern, but that does not make it an anti-pattern. `IngredientsFactory` does not create anything, is just a container and could be called `Recipe`.

The key difference is that approach 1 generates the ingredients inside the factory, whereas approach 2 injects the ingredients from the outside. Approach 1 allows the Chicago store to use a secret recipe for generating ingredients whereas approach 2 requires the Chicago store to let everyone know what the ingredients are.

The choice depends on the application, but neither is right or wrong.

---

Also note that this code in approach 1 won't compile:

```
def createDough: Dough = new ThinDough
def createSauce: Sauce = new RedSauce
```

It should be

```
val createDough: Dough = ThinDough
val createSauce: Sauce = RedSauce
```

Comment: Yes made the changes. So it compiles. Thanks.

Comment: I can think of cases where I don't want to create multiple sub classes and would prefer approach 2. For approach 1 I can only think of the case where my factory methods are closely bound with the type of the sub class, that I don't want them to be injected as you mentioned. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that's about it. I would use approach 2 (because it is simpler) until you really need the extra level of abstraction provided by approach 1.